# Mongodb.Bson BsonBinaryWriter can't write field with name

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson

I'm trying to write int value to BsonBinaryWriter using WriteInt32, but receive exception "WriteName can only be called when State is Name, not when State is Initial".

code sample

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.IO;
        
BsonBinaryWriter writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
writer.WriteInt32("t", 1); // receive exception here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call `WriteStartDocument` first since what you're doing is creating a BSON document. So you're trying to add `t : 1` value, but given that BSON document should roughly speaking correspond to JSON rules, you should open a bracket `{` (via `WriteStartDocument`) and close it at the end of a document (via `WriteEndDocument`).

See:

```
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var writer = new BsonBinaryWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteInt32("t", 1); // receive exception here
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        using var reader = new BsonBinaryReader(memoryStream);
        var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(reader);
        var document = BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(context);
        Console.WriteLine(document.ToString()); // => { "t" : 1 }
```